# Why google didn't prefer javafx or silverlight for google earth?

Tags: java, silverlight

I investigate RIA tools. As you know, there are plenty of RIA products such as Java applets, JavaFX, Silverlight and so on. I try to implement a map program such as Google earth but I saw that Google prefers none of the RIA products, it writes a desktop application. I wonder why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because they can't do what a desktop app can. Especially when it comes to raw rendering performance (Google earth uses C++ and OpenGL/DirectX to render straight to the hardware). Silverlight is WAY too limiting, and both SL and Java have a hard time delivering the performance you need for this type of rendering.
Also Google Earth was earlier "Keyhole" which they bought. This is from way before Silverlight even existed.